# Making 30 using 3 3s

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Hope that all can answer the question. It's an IQ!

> How can one make 30 using 3 only three times?

Answer (score 12):

Well by doing this way :

> 33 - 3 = 30

And another solution :

> 3! * 3! - 3! = 30

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Saeidryl's answer, you can also do

> $3^3 + 3 = 30$. This may be "more" correct depending on whether or not you allow the concatenation of 3's.